Iphone 14 specific media query
I need to apply some CSS only for iPhone 14, but when I am trying to apply Media query in iPhone 14 in that case it also applying in iPhone 15 because both the device having same media query as below
Resolution : 1179x2556
Viewport : 390x844
i tried this one

@media only screen and  (device-width : 390px) and (device-height: 844px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio : 3) and (orientation : portrait) {
    .Chat-section {
        gap: 10px;
        right: 2.5%;
        width: 95svw;
        width: 95vw;
        justify-content: flex-start;
    }
}


Can you explain the problem you are trying to solve... why do you need to specifically target iPhone 14 and NOT iPhone 15?

i have writtren media query for max-width 390px code but  is not reflecting on iphone, then i take screenshot for that it's show width of 1170px. how can i write  the media query for that?

That sounds like you might be missing a proper viewport meta tag to begin with? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Viewport_meta_tag

yes i understand your problem, but there may be another way to solve the issue you are facing... so if you can explain what problem you are trying to solve by targeting only iphone 14 device screen sizes and not iphone 15 then maybe we can suggest a solution for you that does not require forming a specific media query.
